# fmt - use single space between sentences

Tags: linux, command-line, text-formatting, typography

I've noticed that fmt uses two space characters when joining sentences across lines.

**Command:**

```
$ fmt << EOF
Hello world. 
This is a nice place. And a nice website too. I come here
to ask important questions.
Like this one.
EOF
```

**Output:**

```
Hello world.  This is a nice place. And a nice website too. I come here
to ask important questions.  Like this one.
```

Is there a way to turn this behaviour off and use a single space instead?

I know that there's a long debate whether one should use 1 or 2 spaces after the period. But this is not relevant in my case. I want to only partially reformat existing text files, typeset using 1 space after the period.

Comment: I have done some tests, and it appears that the double space occurs only when a period is followed by a new line, although any multiple spaces mid-sentence are maintained. You can reverse this effect by piping the output through `sed 's/\.  /. /g'`. With your here-document, you'll need to start with `{ fmt << EOF` and add `} | sed 's/\.  /. /g'` on the next line. To remove all multiple spaces, use `sed 's/  */ /g'` instead (replace space-space asterisk by space, if the format isn't clear).